# how can I configure the default admin user:password with docker if i am launching docker-compose up of a docker(portainer in my case)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, portainer

I am trying to create a docker-compose which sets up a huge environment of dockers with portainer as a manager.

The problem is that the first time the user use "docker-compose up" and the portainer start running, he has to navigate to portainer web interface (localhost:9000) and set-up the admin user and password.

How can I automate this step and create a portainer with a default user that I define so when the user navigate to portainer on the first time, the admin user is already created.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./portainer/portainer_data:/data
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Portainer allows you to specify an encrypted password from the command line for the admin account. You need to generate the hash value for password.

For example, this is the hash value of password - $$2y$$05$$arC5e4UbRPxfR68jaFnAAe1aL7C1U03pqfyQh49/9lB9lqFxLfBqS

In your docker-compose file make following modification

```
version: '3.3'
 services:
   portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    volumes:
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
     - ./portainer/portainer_data:/data
    command: --admin-password "$$2y$$05$$arC5e4UbRPxfR68jaFnAAe1aL7C1U03pqfyQh49/9lB9lqFxLfBqS"
    ports:
     - "9000:9000"
```

**--admin-password** This flag is used to specify an encrypted password in Portainer.

More information can be found in documentation - [Portainer](http://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape each `$` character inside the hashed password with another `$`:

```
$2y$05$ZBq/6oanDzs3iwkhQCxF2uKoJsGXA0SI4jdu1PkFrnsKfpCH5Ae4G
```

To

```
$$2y$$05$$ZBq/6oanDzs3iwkhQCxF2uKoJsGXA0SI4jdu1PkFrnsKfpCH5Ae4G
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set admin password ONLY for the first run of the container. Use [this repository](https://github.com/MohsenAbasi-Shia/portainer):

Answer (score 0):

Following Mohsen's remark, you must run `docker-compose down`, each time you need to restart and initialise a new admin password, with the option `-v` if you want also to delete the volumes.

https://github.com/portainer/portainer/issues/1506#issuecomment-352273682

Using `version: '3.3'` in the docker-compose.yml file is mandatory in this later case.

Answer (score 0):

I set the admin password directly on Dockerfile!

1. Create a script to generate your password:

```
$ cat <<EOF > portainer-pass.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
    
if [ -z "\$1" ]; then
    echo -e "\\nPlease call '\$0 <password>' to run this command!\\n"
    exit 1
fi
    
htpasswd -nb -B admin \$1 | cut -d ":" -f 2
EOF
```

2. Give your permission:

```
chmod u+x portainer-pass.sh
```

3. generate your password:

```
./portainer-pass.sh c7e694055489cb2051195a2be1740992
```

Output: `$2y$05$bGljp9ThZkfNaZuKvDUB3uKpXecI5SDZ6s6Xga8azv4JQUDXmHV82`

4. Put in "CMD" of the Dockerfile:

```
# Set fixed portainer image
FROM portainer/portainer-ce:latest

# Set default admin password at startup
CMD ["--admin-password", "$2y$05$bGljp9ThZkfNaZuKvDUB3uKpXecI5SDZ6s6Xga8azv4JQUDXmHV82"]

# Default portainer web port
EXPOSE 9443
```

Here you NOT need to be replace `$` to `$$`!